# Unable to cast object error when attempting to return key/value pairs by querying a datacontext

Tags: vb.net

I am attempting to get data from a datacontext.  Normally, I've had no problems doing it, but I'm having trouble trying to return a list of key/value pairs.

Basically I'm attempting to grab all unique names from a table as the key column and the number of times they appear in the table as the value column.

My data would look like this:

```
apple 5
banana 1
dragonfruit 3
.
.
.
```

The full error message is:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[VB$AnonymousType_3`2[System.String,System.Int32]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1

The code I'm using is this:

```
Dim indicators As List(Of Object)

Public Sub GetIndicatorData()
    Using context = new A_DataContext
    indicators = (From p In chartdata Group p By __groupByKey1__ = p.INDK8R Into g = Group
                      Select New With {.name = __groupByKey1__, .count = g.Count()}).AsEnumerable()
    indDataSource = indicators
End Sub
```

but I've also tried to:

1. Return indicators as a list
2. Return indicators as an enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class to encapsulate your anonymous type

```
Public Class NameAndCount
    Public ReadOnly Property Name As String
    Public ReadOnly Property Count as Integer
    Public Sub New(name As String, count As Integer)
        Me.Name = name
        Me.Count = count
    End Sub
End Class

' ...

Private indicators As IEnumerable(Of NameAndCount)

Public Sub GetIndicatorData()
    Using context = new A_DataContext
        indicators = From p In chartdata Group p By __groupByKey1__ = p.INDK8R Into g = Group
                     Select New NameAndCount(__groupByKey1__, g.Count())
        indDataSource = indicators.ToList()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out. I changed the declaration of indicators to simply be an object then removed the .enumerable (or .toList) from the query result.

Thank you for the consideration and time.

Comment: This is probably the wrong approach. The correct thing to have done would have been to change `Dim indicators As List(Of Object)` to `Dim indicators As IEnumerable(Of Object)`. Better yet, you could make a class or tuple so you don't need to pass around enumerables of objects.